# apex:inputField not binding value to controller

Tags: visualforce, field-update, dynamic-apex, apexinputfield

I'm trying to update an Account from a visualforce but so far I haven't managed to be able to save the changes. I'm using `apex:inputField` for the user interface but when I try to save the values they are not updated. My fields are not updating from the visualforce.

Here's the main part of my page:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-body">
            <apex:form>
            <img src="https://allizancespecializedsytems--emorandev.cs2.my.salesforce.com/img/social/unknown_company_pic.png"/>
            <h2 class="margin-bottom-20">{!Account.Name} </h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nombre:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" styleClass="form-control"/>
                                <!--Trying to change this value but is never updated-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </apex:form>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <apex:form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                <apex:commandButton value="Guardar" action="{!updateRecord}" styleClass="btn green"/>
                                <a href="/apex/CustomerPortalAccounts?Id={!account.Id}" class="btn default" role="button">Cancelar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
                </div>
            </apex:form>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is the updateRecord method in my controller:

```
public class CustomerPortalController {

    static final String URL_PARAM_ACCOUNT = 'Id';
    static final String URL_PARAM_CONTACT = 'contactId';
    static final String URL_PARAM_OPPORTUNITY = 'opportunityId';
    static final String URL_PARAM_SYSTEM = 'systemId';
    static final String URL_PARAM_EDIT = 'edit';

    public Account account{get;set;}
    public Contact contact{get;set;}
    public Opportunity opportunity{get;set;}
    public Sistemas__c sistem {get;set;}

    public String showAccountDetails{get;set;}
    public String showAccountList{get;set;}
    public String showAccountEdit{get;set;}

    public String accountId{get;set;}
    public String contactId{get;set;}
    public String opportunityId{get;set;}

    public String page{get;set;}

    public String accountName{get;set;}

    public List<Sistemas__c> sistemas{get;set;}

    public CustomerPortalController() {

        accountId     = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(URL_PARAM_ACCOUNT);
        contactId     = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(URL_PARAM_CONTACT);
        opportunityId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(URL_PARAM_OPPORTUNITY);

        if(accountId != null){
            this.account = [Select Id,Name,Externo_temp__c,Phone,BillingCountry,BillingPostalCode,BillingState,BillingCity,Colonia__c,BillingStreet,Industry from Account where Id=:accountId];

            ParamValidation validationAccountId =  validatePageParam(URL_PARAM_ACCOUNT);
            this.showAccountDetails             = validationAccountId.showDetails;
            this.showAccountList                = validationAccountId.showList;
            this.showAccountEdit                = validationAccountId.showEdit;
        }
        else if(contactId != null){
            this.contact = [Select Id,Name,Title, Email from Contact where Id=:contactId];

            ParamValidation validationAccountId =  validatePageParam(URL_PARAM_CONTACT);
            this.showAccountDetails             = validationAccountId.showDetails;
            this.showAccountList                = validationAccountId.showList;
            this.showAccountEdit                = validationAccountId.showEdit;
        }
        else if(opportunityId != null){
            this.opportunity = [Select Id,Name,LeadSource,Amount,StageName,CloseDate from Opportunity where Id=:opportunityId];
            this.sistemas = [Select Id, Name, GM_TOTAL__c, MG_MEX__c, MG_US__c, Area_FT2__c, Bonds__c, Clase__c,
                             Cost_Hr_Eng__c,Cost_Hr_Installation__c,Cost_Hr_Supervision__c,Costo_MEX__c,
                             Costo_Total__c,Costo_USA__c,Cotizacion__c,Days__c,Engineering__c,Engineering_Trave__c,
                             Equipment__c,Equipo_Mayor__c,Fabrication__c,Freight__c,Import_Duties__c,Inst_Travel__c,
                             Installation__c,Installation_Cost__c,Local_Material__c,Material__c,Obra_Civil__c,
                             Oportunidad__c,Otros__c,Paint__c,Partida__c,Per_Team__c,Precio_Mex__c,Precio_Total__c,
                             Precio_USA__c,Se_Cotiza__c,Sistema__c,Sub_Contrato__c,Supervision__c,Supervision_Cost__c,
                             Tipo_de_Cambio__c,Total__c,Unidad__c,Union__c,Vendedor__c,Version__c
                             from Sistemas__c where Oportunidad__r.Id=:opportunityId];


            ParamValidation validationAccountId =  validatePageParam(URL_PARAM_OPPORTUNITY);
            this.showAccountDetails             = validationAccountId.showDetails;
            this.showAccountList                = validationAccountId.showList;
            this.showAccountEdit                = validationAccountId.showEdit;
        }
        else{
            this.showAccountDetails             = 'none';
            this.showAccountEdit                = 'none';
            this.showAccountList                = '';
        }
    }

    public List<Account> getAccounts(){

        List<Account> accountsAvailable = [Select Id,Name,CreatedDate,Externo_temp__c,Phone from Account];
        return accountsAvailable;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContacts(){
        List<Contact> contact_list;
        if(accountId!=null){
            contact_list = [Select Id,Name,FirstName,LastName,Email,CreatedDate,Title from Contact where AccountId = :accountId];
        }
        else{
            contact_list = [Select Id,Name,FirstName,LastName,Email,CreatedDate,Title from Contact];
        }

        if(contact_list.size()>0){
            return contact_list;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities(){
        List<Opportunity> opportunity_list = [Select Id,Name,CreatedDate,CloseDate,StageName,Amount,LeadSource from Opportunity where AccountId = :accountId];
        if(opportunity_list.size()>0){
            return opportunity_list;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getAccountIndustry() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Schema.Account.Industry.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getBillingStates() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Schema.Account.BillingState.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getBillingCountries() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Schema.Account.BillingCountry.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public ParamValidation validatePageParam(String paramName){
        String result = '';
        ParamValidation validation = new ParamValidation();

        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(paramName) != null) {
            validation.showList = 'none';

            String editMode = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(URL_PARAM_EDIT);
            if (editMode != null) {
                validation.showDetails = editMode == 'true' ? 'none' : '';
                validation.showEdit = editMode == 'true' ? '' : 'none';
            } else {
                validation.showDetails = '';
                validation.showEdit = 'none';
            }
        } else {
            validation.showList = '';
            validation.showDetails = 'none';
            validation.showEdit = 'none';
        }
        return validation;
    }

    public class ParamValidation{
        public String showList{get;set;}
        public String showDetails{get;set;}
        public String showEdit{get;set;}
    }

    public PageReference editRecord() {
        String editUrl = '';
        if (accountId != null) {
            editUrl = 'CustomerPortalAccounts?Id=' + accountId + '&';
        } else if (opportunityId != null) {
            editUrl = 'CustomerPortalOpportunities?opportunityId=' + opportunityId + '&';
        } else if (contactId != null) {
            editUrl = 'CustomerPortalContacts?contactId=' + contactId + '&';
        }
        PageReference editPage = new PageReference('/apex/' +  editUrl + URL_PARAM_EDIT + '=true');
        editPage.setRedirect(true);
        return editPage;
    }

    public void updateRecord() {
        try {
            System.debug('About to update');
            System.debug('Simple var: ' + accountName);
            System.debug(account);
            update account;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.debug('Fail!!! ' + e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
        /*PageReference detailPage = new PageReference('/apex/CustomerPortalAccounts?Id=' + accountId);
        detailPage.setRedirect(true);
        return detailPage;*/
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the values not getting updated. can you be more precise. Put a debug for each individual values and trace that

Comment: @SantanuBoral I've shortened the code to make it more clear. Just now I'm trying to update the account name, but when `updateRecord ` get's called, no matter what I type on my `inputField` the account name remains the same.

Comment: I think that is lookup field of Account, check my ans

Comment: @CarlosJiménez - You are most likely getting a DML exception. Do you have a page messages component on your VF page? If not add it so you can see the message. You can also place a debug in the catch block and a return null in the catch block so you are not redirected in the case of an error

Comment: @Eric, I do have a page messages tag on my page and I am logging the exceptions but I am not getting one. What could it be?

Comment: @CarlosJiménez - Your code does not show you logging exceptions. You do the DML, catch the exception, then redirect back to the Record View page thus you will never see the error

Comment: @Eric I just updated my code with the logging. Also, the redirect is commented for now but still I don't get exceptions or messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple forms on your page. You button is in a separate form so when you submit it does not grab the value from the input fields in the other form.

Wrap you entire code in the form as follows:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <apex:form styleClass="form-horizontal" html-role="form">
        <div class="form-body">
            <img src="https://allizancespecializedsytems--emorandev.cs2.my.salesforce.com/img/social/unknown_company_pic.png"/>
            <h2 class="margin-bottom-20">{!Account.Name} </h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nombre:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" styleClass="form-control"/>
                                <!--Trying to change this value but is never updated-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                <apex:commandButton value="Guardar" action="{!updateRecord}" styleClass="btn green"/>
                                <a href="/apex/CustomerPortalAccounts?Id={!account.Id}" class="btn default" role="button">Cancelar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</div>
```

Note: I also removed your html form tag. Not sure of the top of my head if the apex:form allows html passthrough attributes.

Comment: Thanks Eric. That was the problem! the html tag seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Eric, I have just overlooked the `apex:form` which you have pointed out correctly

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `apex:inputField` to display Account as lookup then use the `Id` instead of `Name`.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!account.Id}"/>
```

If you use `apex:inputtext` then use `"{!account.Name}"` to display the account name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using `apex:inputText` but the account name is not changed either.

Comment: what type of user is changing this name? portal user?

Comment: right now I'm testing as an administrator

Comment: is that other values are saving?

Comment: None of the values are saving

Comment: is that "About to update" is printed in log?

Comment: Yeah, the method gets called. I can see the log on the console, but the name of the account before the update is the same as in the begining. The `inputField` is not passing it's value to account.Name

Comment: use `account.Id` and check

Comment: I just did. But the field is now showing the account id instead of the name. [Screenshot](https://snag.gy/x0vzY3.jpg)

Comment: Can you post controller code, I think there are other issues which is not because of this method